# Reading cookies set at a particular domain

Tags: php, cookies

I currently store cookies on my site at `.domain.com`, as I have a few subdomains that share the cookies (like authentication). I wanted to setup a test site so I could show some features publicly, so I setup a `test.domain.com`, which obviously gets the `.domain.com` cookies, but I'd like it not to. Is there some way for me to set it up so my test site reads only the cookies at `.test.domain.com`?

Answer (score 0):

The 2 domains `mydomain.com` and `subdomain.mydomain.com` can only share cookies if the domain is explicitly named in the `Set-Cookie` header. Otherwise, the scope of the cookie is restricted to the request host.

For instance, if you sent the following header from `subdomain.mydomain.com`:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

Then the cookie won't be sent for requests to `mydomain.com`. However if you use the following, it will be usable on both domains:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=mydomain.com
```

In [RFC 2109][1], a domain without a leading dot meant that it could not be used on subdomains, and only a leading dot (`.mydomain.com`) would allow it to be used across subdomains.

However, modern browsers respect the newer specification [RFC 6265][2], and will ignore any leading dot, meaning you can use the cookie on subdomains as well as the top-level domain.

In summary, if you set a cookie like the second example above from `mydomain.com`, it would be accessible by `subdomain.mydomain.com`, and vice versa.

See also: [www vs no-www and cookies](http://www.phpied.com/www-vs-no-www-and-cookies/), [this test script](http://scripts.cmbuckley.co.uk/cookies.php)